# How to create a method within a method to create and click on a web element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click on a weblink in Selenium. The weblink has already been created inside the method however it is unreachable inside an if else statement so an error occurs.

```
So what I have tried to do is create a new weblink that refers to the same piece of text. This piece of text is "View" which opens up a new table in the UI.
```

However, in order to create this webelement I need to take in information from parameters. This is what happens when the webelement is created in the method originally.

Here is the code

```
 public void rejectOrRecallPayments(CreditTransferContext ct) {
                   listPayments.click();

                   if(isNotBlank(ct.getRecallReason()) || isNotBlank(ct.getRejectReason())) {
                   final WebElement viewLink = getViewLinkFromDisplayTable(resultTable,
    ct.getOriginatorIBAN(), ct.getAmount());
                  System.out.println("ct.getOriginatorIBAN() is "+ct.getOriginatorIBAN());
                  System.out.println("ct.getAmount() is " +ct.getAmount());



                if(isNotBlank(ct.getRecallReason())){
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //This is my attempt to create another "viewLink" in the if else statement
                final WebElement viewLink2 = getViewLinkFromDisplayTable(resultTable,      ct.getOriginatorIBAN(), ct.getAmount());
                viewLink2.click();
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






                recallPayment.click();                 
                viewCTPage.recallCT().recallCT(ct);     
            }else if(isNotBlank(ct.getRejectReason())){
                rejectPayment.click();
                viewCTPage.rejectCT().reject(ct);
            }
            listPayments.click();
        }
        //}




    }
```

Basically, how can I create a Weblink inside an if else statement. Is it possible to call a method that creates another, identical weblink? 
   Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Selenium, this is purely a Java problem!

```
WebElement viewLink2;
if(...) {
    viewLink2 = getViewLinkFromDisplayTable(resultTable,      ct.getOriginatorIBAN(), ct.getAmount());
    ...
}

viewLink2.click()   // or anything else you need to do with it
```